# UV Unwrapping Issue. No visible stretching, but part of the texture appears stretched

Tags: uv

I'm pretty new to UVs, so I imagine I've overlooked something basic. Can someone point out to me (based on the below image) why the texture appears stretched when the UV editor indicates that the face it's being applied to isn't stretched?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a ton of ngons as a result of, presumably, dissolving edges needlesly.